# Maintaining Task Sequence in Asynchronous Workflow in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, asynchronous

I am trying to do a simple download, after which I receive a JSON file. Then, I would like to convert this object into an NSDictionary and finally do some formatting before I returned the formatted object. I am doing this in a separate class to be all neat and tidy. The idea is to initialize the class and call a function in the class that would initiate the download and spit back an NSDictionary at the end (with error handling if something went wrong along the way).

Here is a flow chart to illustrate what I'd like to achieve:

[image]

The problem is that I cannot wrap my head around how to sequence these tasks together when the download is an asynchronous task and I cannot parse the JSON until the download is finished:

[image]

I know the download task has a completion handler, and I can call the next step when it fires, but then I lose the ability to return the NSDictionary at the end. Similarly, if I make my NSDictionary a property that I can access from outside and store every step in it, how will I know when it contains the end result (upon initialization that dictionary is empty; I need to wait for the sequence to finish)?

So, I am looking for a nice way of handling this seemingly simple download task. I hope I was clear explaining my problem, but if you need any clarification, please let me know.

Lastly, here are a few code snippets of the most relevant steps. This is where I would like to handle the download:

```
- (void) initiateDownload {
// Initialize variables for URL request
NSURL *nasaAPI           = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest    = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nasaAPI];
NSURLSession *urlSession    = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

// Setup session to timeout after a specific time interval
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig    = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest     = 10.0;
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource    = 30.0;

// Initialize the download task
downloadTask    = [urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *downloadError) {
                                    if (downloadError) {
                                        // Error occured, put it into errorMessage dictionary
                                        [self errorReceived:downloadError];
                                    } else if (data) {
                                        [self dataReceived:data];
                                    }
                                }];

// Fire download task
[downloadTask resume];
}
```

And, this is where I handle parsing the JSON I downloaded:

```
- (void) parseWeatherJSON:(NSData *)data {
/* ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 Returns with an NSDictionary with either
 1) the parsed JSON data or 2) an error message.
 ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- */

// Create temporary variables
NSError *jsonError;
NSDictionary *parsedJSON;

// Insiate JSON parsing
parsedJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

// Handle any possible errors
if (jsonError) {
    // JSON parsing did not complete, return error message instead
    errorDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:jsonError, @"error", nil];
    [self errorReceived:jsonError];
} else {
    // JSON parsing was complete, return parsed NSDictionary
    [self dictionaryReceived:parsedJSON];
}
}
```

**Update 1.:** If the above is not the right logic to handle a download/parse sequence, I am more than open to other ideas. That is just how I would do it, but I am not a trained programmer. There are probably better ways.

Comment: why you don't add a completion block as parameters in your `initiateDownload `method?

Comment: I don't know how. :) I forgot to mention that I am a beginner/intermediate developer (just doing this in my spare time). I can do a lot of stuff on my own, but I need help with advance tasks sometimes. This is one of those occasions. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. add completion block with parameter of dictionary.
2. inintiate download and parse data into dictionary in your completionHandler from session
3. call the completion block with parsed dictionary as a parameter

Comment: Hi Heisenburg, 

Would you mind showing this in code? I don't yet know how to do this.

Comment: Sure, I can provide some code. BTW if you are starting with iOS, why you don't use Swift?

Comment: I'm not starting, I've been doing it for 4-6 years; hence my reluctance to start a brand new language. BTW, I have given Swift a chance but didn't get very far with it. Obj C seem more logical and easier to follow to me.

Answer (score -1):

[How Do I Declare A Block in Objective-C?](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/)

Here is an example.

```
// declare in .h
typedef void(^ResponseCallback)(NSError *error, id result);


- (void) initiateDownloadWithCompletion:(ResponseCallback)completion {
    ...

    downloadTask = [urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *downloadError) {
        if (downloadError) {
            completion(downloadError, nil);
        } else if (data) {
            [self parseWeatherJSON: data completion: completion];
        }
    }];

    ...
}


- (void) parseWeatherJSON:(NSData *)data completion:(ResponseCallback)completion {
    ...

    if (jsonError) {
        ...
        completion(jsonError, nil);
    } else {
        ...
        completion(nil, parsedJSON);
    }
}
```